# How to navigate users to other pages in the website without losing socket connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-applications, socket.io

I want to build a simple web application using socket.io and express, the website will include 2 pages:
(**Rooms** page and **room** page).
The rooms page is where the user needs to insert his name and he can create his own room or join an existing room from the room list.
On the room page, I want to wait for 2 users and then display a trivia question.

How do I redirect users to the **room** page from the **rooms** page without losing socket connection? When I try to do it with HTML tag 'a' with "href" attribute it doesn't work.
I guess it because the page is reloading so how can I navigate to other pages and keep the socket connection on?

Answer (score 0):

You have just described a key reason that Single Page Application frameworks are so popular - you can change the user's view without reloading or interrupting data connections to the server.

In your example, as soon as you request the other page from the server the socket.io connection will disconnect and then reconnect when the next page is ready.  You can use console.log statements to confirm this behavior.

So no, it's not possible using Express unless you start considering workarounds like frames or iframes that separate pages, or maybe timestamps on the client that can "catch up" the newly loaded page.  Neither are good options.

React, Angular, and Vue are the three most popular SPA frameworks, if your app is advanced enough to need a constant socket.io connection then chances are you will benefit from using one of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to make sure, is Ajax doesn't suitable here ? the solution to my problem is SPA framework (for navigate users to other pages and display them different HTML pages) ?

Comment: SPA frameworks use Ajax extensively.  I would strongly recommend that you stop coding for a little while and start reading articles and tutorials about this, as there seems to be a large gap between your current understanding and the baseline knowledge that would be required to implement anything more than a basic socket.io application.